# Why won't my tkinter widgets stretch using sticky and column/row weights

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating a GUI in Tkinter. I've tried over and over trying to get my widgets stretch with my GUI. I'm using the sticky commands and col/row weights. On the design viewer tab, I want the Listbox to stretch vertically with the window and I want the Canvas with the blue box to stretch Vertically and Horizontally. I added an image for clarification of what I would expect to happen.

[image]

Thanks in advance! Here is my code:

```
    # Gui 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import N,W,S,E
from tkinter import messagebox
class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.grid(sticky = N+E+S+W)
        self.create_application_foundation()

    def create_application_foundation(self):
        # Create menubar ribbon

        self.topRibbon = tk.Frame(self, bg = "#E3E5E6")
        self.topRibbon.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)


        # Initialize Buttons
        width = 15; height = 2; bg = "#F5F6F7"; relief = "flat"; bd = 0; padx = 1
        self.designViewerButton = tk.Button(self.topRibbon, text = "Design\nViewer", width = width,
                                         height = height, bg = bg, relief = relief, bd = bd)
        self.patternCreatorButton = tk.Button(self.topRibbon, text = "Pattern\nCreator",width = width,
                                                height = height, bg = bg, relief = relief, bd = bd)

        # Add buttons to ribbon
        self.designViewerButton.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = padx, sticky = N+W)
        self.patternCreatorButton.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = padx, sticky = N+W)

        # Create design viewer window
        self.createdesignViewerWindow()
        self.createObjectCreator()

        # Try to make things expandable
        self.topRibbon.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.topRibbon.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    def createdesignViewerWindow(self):
        width = 30; height = 1; bg = "#F5F6F7"; relief = "flat"; bd = 0; pady = 1

        # Create window
        self.designViewerWindow = tk.Frame(self, bg = "#E3E5E6")
        self.designViewerWindow.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky =W+E+N+S)

        # Create object button
        self.objectButton = tk.Button(self.designViewerWindow, text = "Object", width = width,
                                            height = height, bg = bg, relief = relief, bd = bd)
        self.objectButton.grid(row = 0, sticky =N+W, pady = pady)

        # Create object listbox
        self.objectListBox = tk.Listbox(self.designViewerWindow)        
        objects = ["Object {}".format(i) for i in range(50)]
        self.objectListBoxFrame = tk.Frame(self.designViewerWindow)
        self.objectsListBox = tk.Canvas(self.objectListBoxFrame, width=100, height=200)
        self.objectsListBox.grid(row = 0, rowspan = 5,column = 0, sticky = N+S)
        self.objectListBoxFrame.grid(row = 1, sticky = N+S, pady = pady)

        # Create canvas with blue rectangle
        self.imageCanvas = tk.Canvas(self.designViewerWindow, width=200, height=100)
        self.imageCanvas.grid(row = 0, rowspan = 5,column = 1, columnspan = 5, sticky = N+E+S+W)
        self.imageCanvas.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")
        self.imageCanvas.config(bg = "white")

        # Attempt to make window expandable        
        self.designViewerWindow.rowconfigure(1,weight = 1)
        self.designViewerWindow.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    def createObjectCreator(self):
        self.objectCreatorWindow = tk.Frame(self,bg = "#E3E5E6")
        self.tempLabel = tk.Label(self.objectCreatorWindow, text = "Object Creator").grid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("My Program")
    root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    # root.minsize(400,200)
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is just way too much code. Can you please try to reduce it down to a [mcve]? For example, we don't need any of the menubar code, or any of the functions. Just give us the code that lays out the widgets, and enough extra code to make that work.

Comment: Yes. Give me a couple of minutes

Comment: I've reduced my code down to a couple of buttons and boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the problem is that you haven't configured the app to fill the window, so anything inside the app won't fill the window.

You seem to be attempting to, but you're giving all of the weight in the root window to row and column 1, but you're putting `app` in row and column 0. You need to give the weight to row and column 0:

```
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Note: if you only have one widget in a container, it's easier to use pack since you can configure it to fill the window with just one line of code rather than three.

For example:

```
self.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

... versus

```
self.grid(sticky = N+E+S+W)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

The next problem is that you're putting widgets in the `Application` frame with `grid`, but you haven't given weight to any rows or columns in the `Application` frame. So once again, this frame won't fill its parent so any widget inside won't fill the window either.

I think you want column 0 to get all of the extra space, but you want row 1 to be the row that gets the extra space since that's where `self.designViewerWindow` is.

Add the following to the `__init__` of `Application`:

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ...
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        ...
```

There are other problems, but this shows the general problem: you aren't properly configuring the rows and columns for each group of widgets. As a rule of thumb, for every widget that has children managed by `grid` you need to give a positive weight to at least one row and one column.

This would all be a bit easier to see if you grouped together all of the calls to `grid` for children of the same widget, and then added the `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` commands in the same place. That way you can easily see all of the grid options for each group at a glance.